# Affiliate Custom Campaign Parameters reports in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, url-parameters, affiliate, utm-parameters, custom-variables

I am using an affiliate software which automatically passes custom parameters for all affiliate traffic. This custom parameter variable name doesn't match with standard Google campaign parameters.

So my final URL is something like this

https://www.example.com/affiliate_name=AFF_NAME&affiliate_id=AFF_ID&utm_source=affiliate

(utm_source is also passed by the affiliate system)

I want to track affiliate_name and affiliate_id and prepare a report under my Google Analytics. Since these are not the standard variables, I am unable to find them in Google Analytics.

So how can I track this?